# How to remove div from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="abc">    
    <div style="">
       <div style="">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gm-style-iw">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery:

```
var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
iwOuter.parent().remove();
```

How to remove parent of this div, to show html:

```
<div id="abc">
    <div class="gm-style-iw">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to remove the parent or the silbing of `.gm-style-iw`? in your question you want to remove the parent but in you code the sibling is removed.which is which?`div#abc` is the parent of `.gm-style-iw` while the div without any id or class is a sibling the one that you removed.

Answer (score 0):

The div you wanted to remove is immediate previous sibling of `.gm-style-iw` element and not its parent. you need to use `.prev()` selector along with `.gm-style-iw` selector to target it:

```
$('.gm-style-iw').prev().remove();
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nabyLxg4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( ".gm-style-iw" ).siblings().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:not()` to exclude `.gm-style-iw` from being removed from `#abc` parent element

```js
$("#abc div:not(.gm-style-iw)").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="abc">    
    <div style="">
       <div style="">style ...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gm-style-iw">
    gm-style-iw...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()` to exclude your elements to not be removed:

```js
$('#abc > div:not(.gm-style-iw)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
  <div style="">
    <div style="">to be removed...?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gm-style-iw">
    gm-style-iw
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Issue with your code:

```
var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw'); // selector : correct
iwOuter.parent().remove(); // but the target element is not the parent
                           // that is sibling of it.
```